# Why can't I set a metadata content provider on Plex?

Tags: macos, metadata

There's no `Set Content` button when I add a media source in Plex (0.9.3.4) to select a metadata provider.

I've installed Plex on a Mac Mini running Lion and added a content source.  To add the source, I went to `Video Plugins -> Add Source`.  I added a folder called `movies` from my smb share by clicking Browse, selecting the folder, and clicking OK.

Now all tutorials and screenshots I've seen show a "Set Content" button on the Add Video Source menu, and this button allows you to set a metadata content provider.  I see all the buttons (Browse, Add, Remove, OK, Cancel) *except* Set Content.

How do I set a metadata provider for Plex if there's no Set Content button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plex comes with 2 components:  The browser and the media manager or media server.  The media manager is what manages your movie library.  If you just go into `Video Plugins` and select `Add Source`, then Plex just treats it as a random collection of videos, not movies, and you cannot assign a metadata provider.

To add movies with the metadata providers, you have to [add them to the Media Manager](http://wiki.plexapp.com/index.php/PlexNine_PMS_MediaManager).  You access the media manager by clicking on the small Plex icon up by your system clock.